# PySpark dynamic Column Renaming not working

Tags: azure, pyspark, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically rename column in Pyspark using below method. But only one column is getting renamed not all

```
target_schema : ['customer_Number', ' product_Number', ' Payment_Term', ' DateTime', ' Company_ID', ' Company_Number', ' Col1', ' Col2']
source_schema : ['customerID', ' productID', ' Paymentterm', ' datetime', ' xyzID']

display(df_xyz)
```

[output of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tYzJ.png)

```
df_rename_schema = df_xyz.select([col(c).alias(source_target_mapping.get(c, c)) for c in df_xyz.columns])

df_modified_source_schema = df_rename_schema.columns
print(df_modified_source_schema)

Output : ['productID', 'customer_Number', 'Paymentterm', 'datetime', 'xyzID']

Expected Output : ['product_Number', ' customer_Number', ' Payment_Term', 'DateTime','Company_ID']
```

Please help what is wrong here and how to achieve the solution

Comment: Can you share the `source_target_mapping` map, I see that the column names contains spaces and maybe the dict does not contain spaces forcing `source_target_mapping.get(c, c)` to return the default value which is the source column name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `source_target_mapping` does not account for spaces in column names of `df_xyz`. You can strip the spaces from the column names before the lookup operation.

```
df_rename_schema = df_xyz.select([F.col(c).alias(source_target_mapping.get(c.strip(), c)) for c in df_xyz.columns])
```